# showing the default about dialog

Tags: macos, cocoa

Most Cocoa apps come with a "About App" menu item. This opens an dialog that often is not custom but instead provided. It shows the icon and some information from the application bundle.

[image]

I cannot seem to find any information/documentation on how to open this dialog in code.

I have an app written in swift that does not use xib/storyboards so there is no default "About" menu item. While writing a custom one isn't exactly hard I am still wondering how to just open the standard one.

Any pointers to documentation or code snippets? I failed to find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`orderFrontStandardAboutPanel(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428724-orderfrontstandardaboutpanel) on the application instance

```
NSApp.orderFrontStandardAboutPanel(nil)
```

Comment: Ha! I knew it must be simple. Thanks!